# Data binding with Java

Tags: java, swing, data-binding

I have an application with several windows/views that show the same object. For example I have a user object with name and location Strings and an ImageIcon for their picture.

Then on my windows I will use the details of that user object like this -

1. I create a JPanel.
2. I add JLabels to it (nameLabel, locationLabel, imageLabel)
3. I call setText() (or setIcon for imageLabel) for each of these labels to set their text/image to the user object data.

I have to repeatedly do this for

1. each window where the user object's data is shown
2. every time the user object is changed I have to call setText() on the labels again.

In C# when I was using databinding so when I updated an object it was automatically reflected in the GUI element that was databound to it. Does something similar exist with Java?

Comment: please and your question(s) is/are about ???, please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating your issue(s) with Bindings/DataBinding

Comment: I laid out exactly what Im doing in the list above. Not every question requires an SSCCE particularly one like this which is not asking about a code problem. I am asking if databinding is possible with java because in C# it is that standard way of doing GUI work. I have not found any offical sun endorsed java databinding info on google and the first page google results i get for 'Java databinding' contains stuff like 'java databinding api not ready for the primetime' and 'Beans Binding: A Java Data-Binding Solution with a Serious Problem'

Comment: well then your answers could be bellows or JSR296

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is [Property Change Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)

Answer (score 5):

There's a example in the [Java SE Application Design](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html) article of data binding.

See the `AbstractModel` that uses `PropertyChangeSupport`.

The classes that need to notice that the object has changed will implement `PropertyChangeListener` (see `AbstractController`).

Answer (score 4):

MVP pattern helps you achieve this. You have to write raise custom events and attach UI listeners to respond to these events (observer pattern). Java provides PropertyChangeEvents and PropertyChangeListeners in additional to Observer and Observable contracts.

Answer (score 0):

I've been coding with java and c# for a long time and
I've coded my own propertyChangeListeners in Java by imitating .net and here below my method.

For serialization of this object I coded special filters against  serializer ,i.e. XStream , java native object serialization

If you need to DIY you may use my way or you may also progress by going through Oracle's infrastructure as @Pau Kiat Wee linked it in his/her answer.

Have a look JGoodies for Swing data binding for more already built in stuff http://www.jgoodies.com/download/presentations/binding.pdf
http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/demos/

**Here is my implementation,**

Your business object will be extended from this abstract class.

> Sure, if you are already extending from something else and this is not
>   one of yours this option impossibly work for you.

Most possibly you have no intention to serialize `propertyChangeListeners` registrants and send some data to somewhere with it(a remote service which doesn't know your UI dependent class and this will be headache).So,we are skipping serialization by this way.

> Please notice  `private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream
>   out)` and `private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)`
>   signatures. I intentionally left them empty and these significant
>   method signatures are considered by `Java Object Serialization`.

This is our PropertyChangeEvent imitated interface,we will use observer pattern to notify our registrants.

```
public interface IPropertyChangedListener extends EventListener {

    public void onPropertyChanged(Object source,String propertyName,Object oldValue,Object newValue);

}
```

This is our base of DataBusinessObject

```
public abstract class DataObjectBase implements Serializable {


    private List<IPropertyChangedListener> propertyChangeListeners=new ArrayList<IPropertyChangedListener>();   
    public void addOnPropertyChangedListener(IPropertyChangedListener propertyChangeListener)
    {   
        ensureRegisterListCreated();
        propertyChangeListeners.add(propertyChangeListener);
    }

    public void removeOnPropertyChangedListener(IPropertyChangedListener propertyChangeListener)
    {
        ensureRegisterListCreated();
        propertyChangeListeners.remove(propertyChangeListener);
    }

    public DataObjectBase()
    {
        ensureRegisterListCreated();
    }

    public void ensureRegisterListCreated()
    {
        if(propertyChangeListeners==null)
            propertyChangeListeners=new ArrayList<IPropertyChangedListener>();      
    }

    protected void onPropertyChanged(Object source,String propertyName,Object oldValue,Object newValue)
    {
        if(propertyChangeListeners.size()<=0)
            return;
        for (IPropertyChangedListener listener : propertyChangeListeners) {
            listener.onPropertyChanged(source, propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
        }
    }

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
             throws IOException
             {

             }

     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
              throws IOException {


              }

}
```

Now , lets use it

```
dataObject.addOnPropertyChangedListener(new IPropertyChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPropertyChanged(Object source, String propertyName,
                        Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s",propertyName,oldValue,newValue));
//TODO:Fire your UI change now !!!

                }
            });
```

Here is what you need to do in your dataObject

```
public class dataObject extends BaseDataObject
{

    private String editable;

    public String getEditable() {
       return editable;
    }

    public void setEditable(String isEditable) {
        String oldValue=this.editable;      
        this.editable = isEditable;
        onPropertyChanged(this,"Editable",oldValue,isEditable);
    }

}
```

If you don't wanna do my way, or you can't for some reason. You should follow JGoodies, this seem the best one of all.
In demos download JNLP file and you you will see DataBinding part. There is code section when you click on an arrow placed up-right. Good luck!
http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/demos/

Comment: Implementing Serializable and then leaving readObject and writeObject *empty* makes no sense at all.

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere thanks for your comment. I can't recap 2016, but it might be to ensure all object are serializable which are inheriting from that class. 
A default implementation could be better, but still it can be overridden and different serializations can be implemented. I think it was just to say DataObjectBase should be serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Use betterbeansbinding.jar file instead of beansbinding.jar